# How to auto increment numbers with using loops in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I'm new in shell and am trying to do auto increment like this

```
  1 | odd
  1 | odd
  1 | odd
  2 | even
  2 | even
  2 | even
  3 | odd
  3 | odd
  3 | odd
```

and i was tried like this

```
 i=1
 for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ ))
 do
    if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 1 ]
    then
            echo "$i | odd"
    else
            echo "$i | even"
    fi
 done
```

but am getting output like this

```
 1 | odd
 2 | even
 3 | odd
```

anyone help me where can i change the script....

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem... Do you want to print the message 3 times for iteration? You can just replace your `echo`s with `echo -e "$i | odd\n$i | odd\n$i | odd"` and `echo -e "$i | even\n$i | even\n$i | even"`

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you trying to do? what is the requested output ?

Comment: creates a file with first column as interger which should be a auto incremental from 1 is 7times, 2 is 7 times and 3 is 7 times and second column with information as Even Integer (or) Odd Integer based on the first Column..

Comment: You need another for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want.

But following your example, it would be something like :

```
 for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ ))
 do
    if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 1 ]
    then
            for (j=1; j<=3; j++)
            do
                echo "$i | odd"
            done
    else
            for (j=1; j<=3; j++)
            do
                echo "$i | even"
            done
    fi
 done
```